# How to validate a dependent text box in Angular

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a checkbox, and if selected, an associated text box must not be empty.
Should I use a directive for this case, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use a directive.

You need to set up a `$watch` on the field you're matching, to check if the other field being changed makes the two match, and also add a parser to check whether updates to the current field match the other field.

If you hook into the `ngModelController` you can take advantage of all the inbuilt validation stuff.

Something like this (coffeescript):

```
.directive('pxnMatchField', ($parse)->
  restrict: 'A'
  require: '?ngModel'

  link: (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel)->
    if !ngModel
      return console.warn "no model specified on match field element"

    scope.$watch("#{attrs.pxnMatchField}", (newVal)->
      ngModel.$setValidity('pxnMatchField', (newVal is ngModel.$viewValue))
    )

    # Dom input validation
    ngModel.$parsers.push((domVal)->
      ngModel.$setValidity('pxnMatchField', 
                           (domVal is $parse(attrs.pxnMatchField)(scope)))
      return domVal
    )
)
```

This then works with the following markup (jade):

```
  label Password
    input(ng-model="password")
  label Confirm Password
    input(ng-model="confirmPassword", pxn-match-field="password")
```